# Adding a value to a set of strings within a map

Tags: java, collections, set, maps

I have a map, handicapMap, with a key of integers, and values which are sets of strings. The map has been populated with test data, and I now wish to add individual values to the sets of strings. I made an attempt at it, but can't get it to compile

```
public class HandicapRecords
{
   private Map<Integer, Set<String>> handicapMap;

   public HandicapRecords()
   {
      handicapMap = new HashMap<>();

   }

   public void handicapMap()
   {
     Set<String> players = new HashSet<>();

     players.add("Michael");
     players.add("Roger"); 
     players.add("Toby");
     handicapMap.put(10, players);

     players = new HashSet<>();
     players.add("Bethany");
     players.add("Martin");
     handicapMap.put(16, players);

     players = new HashSet<>();
     players.add("Megan");
     players.add("Declan");
     handicapMap.put(4, players);
   }

public void addValue(int aKey, String aValue)
{
 handicapMap.put(aKey, players.add(aValue)); \\what I had already tried
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set#add` returns `boolean`, depending essentially on whether the value has been added - see [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29).

The idiom you want to use to add a new value to a `Map` value (i.e. a `Set<String>`), given its key is:

```
handicapMap.get(aKey).add(aValue);
```

You should probably also check for null `Map` values first:

```
Set<String> theValue = handicapMap.get(aKey);
if (theValue != null) {
    theValue.add(aValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class HandicapRecords {

private Map<Integer, Set<String>> handicapMap;

public HandicapRecords() {
    handicapMap = new HashMap<>();

}
Set<String> players = new HashSet<>();

public void handicapMap() {

    players.add("Michael");
    players.add("Roger");
    players.add("Toby");
    handicapMap.put(10, players);

    players = new HashSet<>();
    players.add("Bethany");
    players.add("Martin");
    handicapMap.put(16, players);

    players = new HashSet<>();
    players.add("Megan");
    players.add("Declan");
    handicapMap.put(4, players);
}

public void addValue(int aKey, String aValue) {
    players.add(aValue);
    handicapMap.put(aKey, players);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `Set<String> players` either as instance variable or local inside amethod,and dont forget to check whether map is `null` or not,since this can cause `NPE`.

```
public void addValue(int aKey, String aValue)
{
 Set<String> players = new HashSet<>();
 if(handicapMap!=null){
 handicapMap.put(aKey, players.add(aValue)); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public void addValue(int aKey, String aValue)
{

    if (handicapMap.containsKey(aKey)) {

        handicapMap.get(aKey).add(aValue); // May want to add a check if the key has no values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check whether or not there was already a mapping for that key. If this was the case you only need to add the value to the existing set. Else, you need to first create the set and add it to your map and then add the new value to that set.

```
public void addValue(int aKey, String aValue)
{
    Set<String> players = handicapMap.get(aKey);

    if (players == null) {
        players = new HashSet<>();
        handicapMap.put(aKey, players);
    }

    players.add(aValue);
}
```